# How to generate diff header with file index?

Tags: git, diff

Here is the header:

```
Index: dir1/file1.c
===================================================================
--- dir1.orig/file1.c
+++ dir1/file1.c
```

How to make `diff` or `git` generate such header?

Comment: If I recall correctly, those "Index:" lines are typical of diffs generated by RCS or CVS, and are not produced by `diff` itself at all.

Comment: Good to know that. So how do I generate such header with Git?

Comment: Just run `git diff` (with additional arguments/flags as desired).  Git will insert the index lines as needed.

Comment: `git diff` does not produce such header.

Comment: Why do you need those lines in the first place? Maybe we can help you with the end goal instead of this detail.

Comment: Because I see some files with these lines and I'm curious how to generate it. There's no document mentioned about this type of header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to generate. It's the header generated by `quilt` utility. Read more here: [How To Survive With Many Patches
or
Introduction to Quilt](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/i386_deb50/os/usr/share/doc/quilt/quilt.html)